# Icons not showing in my Expo-based React Native App

Tags: react-native, expo, icons, font-awesome

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import styles from './styles';

export default function LiveCalls( { navigation }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <FontAwesome name="search" size={204} color="black" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

My app runs okay. I'm not getting an errors or warnings. But – no icons are showing. Not even a mysterious "X", where the icon should be. Just nothing. Empty space. Nada. Zilch.

I did check the @expo folder in my node_modules directory to make sure that it's in there... and it is.

I also double checked my icon name, to make sure there was an actual icon in the icon set that I was using.

Additionally, I've tried changing sizes (thinking it might just be super tiny), colors (thinking it might be defaulting to transparent or something), and nothing seems to work.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I tried it and it's working maybe you forgot to call your function into your app.js or any other file which is imported in the app.js